# Zero length single line comment leads to parse error

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

not of utmost importance, but I would be interested if someone can explain this behaviour that I get for zero length single line comments both on 11g and 12c, Oracle SQL Developer 17.3.1.279. I especially find the different results from Test 3 (`--a`) and Test 5 (`---`) interesting:

```
-- Test 1
select * from dual;
-- works

-- Test 2
select * from -- comment
dual;
/* works, 'Query Result SQL' shows (note this is 2 lines)
    select * from -- comment
    dual
*/

-- Test 3
select * from --a
dual;
/* works, 'Query Result SQL' shows (note this is 2 lines)
    select * from --a
    dual
*/

-- Test 4
select * from --
dual;
/* does not work, ORA-00903: invalid table name, 'Query Result SQL' shows (note this is 1 line)
    select * from - dual
*/

-- Test 5
select * from ---
dual;
/* does not work, ORA-00903: invalid table name, 'Query Result SQL' shows (note this is 1 line)
    select * from -- dual
*/
```

As per the 10g documentation that I could find, both `--` and `---` should be valid https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements006.htm:

> Begin the comment with -- (two hyphens). Proceed with the text of the
>   comment. This text cannot extend to a new line. End the comment with a
>   line break.

Comment: that is probably a problem of the IDE and has nothing to do with oracle.
in PLSQL Developer all queries work fine

Comment: Strange indeed. Probably to do with the empty comment not closing properly because its interrupting an SQL query. If you add any text to it it works, and even if you do a /**/ it works.

Comment: Tested in Oracle APEX SQL workshop, and it works there as well. Just a bug with SQL Developer it would seem

Comment: alright, thank you guys. I could not find a page to report bugs to oracle sql developer team, so I guess that's the end of this topic. TYVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see comments. this is a bug in oracle sql developer.